# Firefox submitting form even in the case of alerts

Tags: javascript, firefox

We have a requirement that if a user clicks on any link, he should not be able to click on any other link.to achieve this, we have written a java script with incrementing counter.In case , if a user has already clicked on any link we are showing a alert box with some message.On IE its working fine, In Firefox , I am getting the alert for second click but firefox does not stop the processing of first request and refreshes the page even if alert box is untouched.
We are submitting the forms through explicit java scripts.

Hi All PFB the snippets

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
function incrementCount(){
if(counter>0){
alert('Your request already in progress. Please wait.');
return false;
}else{
counter=counter+1;
return true;
}
}
</script>
```

Form submission script:

```
<script>
function fnTest() {
        if(incrementCount()){
        document.FormName.method = "POST";
        document.FormName.action = "SomeURL";
        document.FormName.submit();     
        }else{
        return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Link through which we are submitting the form

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="return fnTest();" title="overview"><span>Test</span></a>
```

Comment: And you expect someone answering this? Without showing your code? Unfortunately wizards that have magic wands and crystal balls allowing to read other people's minds don't visit this site quite often.

Comment: please don't use the comments section to post code snippets as they are unreadable. Go ahead and edit your original question by including this code. Thanks.

Comment: Once form has been submitted it can't be undone. So first click will submit the form, second click will have no actual effect as the form has already been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. If a user clicks on a submit button he should not be able to click a link? You'll need to post your code.

With regards to the form post my guess is you didn't return false onsubmit

> "On IE its working fine, In Firefox ,
>   I am getting the alert for second
>   click but firefox does not stop the
>   processing of first request and
>   refreshes the page even if alert box
>   is untouched"

Well, what's wrong. Firefox is submitting the first request as you want and it shows an alert on the second click. How is IE different? Is FF doing a double submit?

PS: You dont really need to use a counter. Use this code :

```
var handlers = { 
     alert : function(){ 
           alert('Your request is already in progress. Please wait.')
           return false 
     },
     submitForm : function(){
           this.onclick = handlers.alert //this refers to the a tag
           document.FormName.submit()
     }
}

document.getElementById('mysubmitlink').onclick = handlers.submitForm
```

And on your link becomes:

```
`<a href="#" id='mysubmitlink' title="overview"><span>Test</span></a>`
```

Comment: IE doesnt allow the page refresh if we dont click on "OK" of alert.But Firefox 3.6 gives the requested page even if we dont click on "OK" of alert and same alert remains on the requested page.In Firefox 4 , its killing the alert automatically and giving the requested page.

Answer (score 0):

You can allways return false on your onsubmit call.

Comment: how that will help? As per my understanding browser should not do any further processing till alert is clicked.But firefox is doing everything after showing alert box.